# Java program working file but on debugging "Thread suspended"

Tags: java, exception, apache-poi

Please consider the following code:

```
// program is reading data from an excel file, Sheet1 at cell(0,0).

public class Read {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

       File f = new File("sample.xlsx");
       FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
       XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis); // set a breakpoint here
       XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
       String data = sheet.getRow(0).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
       System.out.println(data);
       wb.close();
}}
```

**Program is working fine**, but on debugging with break-point set at creating XSSFWorkbook object, thread is suspended and Eclipse opens "Reader.class".

Following is the stack information:

```
Thread [main] (Suspended (exception NullPointerException))  
InputStreamReader(Reader).<init>(Object) line: not available    
InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStream) line: not available   
...
...
XSSFWorkbook.<init>(InputStream) line: 296  
Read2.main(String[]) line: 20
```

Please tell, what's wrong here?

Comment: When the debugger pauses your code, it generally suspends all Threads. This is normal behavior.

Comment: ok, but why the program is suspended, there are no errors on running. I am getting the correct output on console after run.

Comment: So what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse suspends the thread because a `NullPointerException` has occurred. It looks like you added an [exception breakpoint](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fbreakpoints%2Fref-addexception_viewaction.htm) for `NullPointerException` at some point. This exception is thrown even before you hit the breakpoint that you set. It is caught somewhere else, that is why you don't notice it when you run (not debug) the program.

You can either just hit "Resume" or remove the exception breakpoint in the breakpoints view (Alt-Shift-Q, Q again and search for "breakpoints").

Comment: oh! yes, you are correct. I previously added a "NullPointerException" under "Add Java Exception Breakpoint", which I forgot to remove it. thanks a lot.